# Is there a difference in response speed between two collection in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

For example, I have the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestor
        .instance
        .collection('products')
        .limit(10)
        .get(GetOptions(source: Source.server));
```

Let's say `products` collection has 500 documents and please note that we call `.limit(10)`

**Question 1**
Would the response speed be the same if the `products collection` had a million documents? also please assume that we have the same connection speed between the two cases.

**Question 2**
The same question 1 and the same code but with adding `.where(..)`

I cannot make an actual test myself at the present time due to the difficulty of the number, I want to know the answer to review my application before publishing

Thanks

Comment: "Queries scale with the size of your result set, not the size of your data set, so you’ll get the same performance fetching 1 result from a set of 100, or 100,000,000." Nothing else about the query matters (filters or whatever), if you assume the same size documents and network speed.